# Is it possible to perform user management if the user has logged in using phone authentication?

Tags: firebase, flutter, authentication

I have two methods

1. readData - that reads available data in FirebaseFirestore.
2. saveUserInfoToFirebase - create data in FirebaseFirestore for new registered users.

My problem is how can I manage these two methods when using Firebase Phone authentication.

```
void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(
  PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) async {
    setState(() {
      showLoading = true;
     });

try {
  final authCredential =
      await _auth.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential);

  setState(() {
    showLoading = false;
  });

  final QuerySnapshot result =
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("userPhone").get();

  final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = result.docs;

  documents.forEach((element) {
    print(element.id.toString());
  });

  if (authCredential.user != null) {
    documents.firstWhere((element) {
      if (element.id.toString() == authCredential.user.uid) {
        readData(authCredential.user).then((value) {
          Navigator.pop(context);
          Navigator.push(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyHomePage()));
        });
      }
    }, orElse: () {
      saveUserInfoToFirestore(authCredential.user).then((value) {
        Navigator.pop(context);
        Navigator.push(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyHomePage()));
      });
    });
  }
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  setState(() {
    showLoading = false;
  });

  _scaffoldKey.currentState
      .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(e.message)));
  }
}
```

The problem I am facing right now is that my method does not create a new document in my collection when a new user is registered and it reads the data of the existing document when I register a new user with different crendentials.

Answer (score 1):

```
  if ((documents.singleWhere((element) => element.id.toString() == firebaseUser.uid,
          orElse: () => null)) !=
      null) {
    readData(firebaseUser).then((value) {
      Navigator.pop(context);
      Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyHomePage()));
    });
  } else {
    saveUserInfoToFirestore(firebaseUser).then((value) {
      readData(firebaseUser).then((value) {
        Navigator.pop(context);
        Navigator.push(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyHomePage()));
      });
    });
  }
```